# How to express the days with different temperature?

Tags: phrases, american-english, expression-choice

I am wondering a word to express the daily temperature values between. For example, I would like to describe hot/warm days with temperature > 30 C and the days in range 1-10 C. The range of my temperature values are 1 to 40 C. I have thought to express as

- very hot/warm days (for temperature > 30 C)
- cold days (for temperature 1-10 C)

Would you please suggest any other suitable phrases to express it.

Answer (score 1):

*balmy*- pleasantly warm, *tropical*- hot, *sultry*- hot and humid
*mild/temperate*- warm/in between,
*chilly/chill/nippy*- cool, *freezing/icy/biting/frigid*- cold